# SonarQube and Azure Active Directory Domain services

Tags: azure, active-directory, sonarqube, sonarqube5.3

Since Oauth 2 support will only be here with SonarQube 5.4 I'm trying to make it work with Azure AD DS (preview)
The principle is Azure AD can have a emulation point for legacy AD domain services supporting ntlm kerberos ldap and so on (think of it as a domain controller basically)
I've configured the AAD DS part and updated the dns servers of my sonarqube machine.
The domain resolves properly from sonarqube VM. Then I installed the LDAP module and added this to the sonar config file.
But sonarqube doesn't work anymore when I try that (also tried variations of that)
Note that I'm running on Ubuntu (up to date) with sonarqube 5.3 and the machine is not "joined" to the domain.
Any idea how to make it work? I've found only little documentation about that.
Thanks
`sonar.security.realm=LDAP`
`ldap.windows.compatibilityMode=true`
`sonar.forceAuthentication=true`
`ldap.url=ldap://10.0.0.5:10389`
`ldap.user.baseDn=cn=users,dc=baywetdev,dc=onmicrosoft,dc=com`

Comment: Logs would be helpful. Set `sonar.log.level=TRACE` in `sonar.properties`, restart SonarQube and share the logs/failures when the LDAP connection is attempted.

Comment: Hi,
Sorry for late answer, I didn't have much time to work on that lately.
As they released support for OAuth and AAD I'm going to change my approach and use that instead.
https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-auth-aad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sonarqube released support for AAD via Oauth on march the 8th.
This is now the recommended approach.
For more information see https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-auth-aad